# Adding JS package in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have installed the laravel-echo package in my ionic app using the following command:

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

Now the package has been downloaded, I am having a bit of trouble including this in my app.  I have a sales page in my app where I would like to display real-time updates from my server.

This is a standard javascript library not a typescript one so how do I include this in my page in ionic.

I have searched on google on **"how to include and load javascript package in ionic 3"** and **"how to use laravel-echo in ionic"** but I have found no solution yet.

Comment: Tried this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the similar solution and I got it working this using laravel-echo-ionic , and socket-io.

First make sure you installed

```
npm i laravel-echo-ionic --save
npm install --save socket.io-client
npm install
```

Create a test page

```
ionic g page test-socket
```

and add this to test-socket.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Echo} from 'laravel-echo-ionic';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test-socket',
  templateUrl: 'test-socket.html',
})
export class TestSocketPage {

  echo:any;
  constructor() {
    this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'socket.io',
      host: 'https://yoursocket.com',
      // if you have any token auth
      auth: {
          headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'your token'

          }
      }
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.echo);
   //Enter the channel and add the event you wanna listen
    this.echo.channel('yourchannel')
      .listen('TestEvent', (e) => { 
          console.log(e);
      });
  }
}
```

My orginal answer on github:
https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/190